# How to delete a row from a JTable based on a text field input

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm using netbeans and i'm having trouble when deleting a row in a jTable.
I want to delete a data using a textfield and a button. I've tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
private void btnDelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String text2 = (String)jTextField2.getText();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
if (!text2.equals(model)){
do {
String [] row = {text2};
while(!text2.equals(model));
model.removeRow(WIDTH);
} 
}
```

I also tried to make it like this one, but still doesn't work:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String text = (String)jTextField1.getText();
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
   for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
     {
     for(int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        model.setValueAt(text, i, j);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas? Please make it easy for me to understand.
I'm really a beginner on java and I don't know if I'm using the right code.

Comment: @Pragnesh Khalas. Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have this data

```
First Name        Last Name

  Lebron           James
  Michael          Jordan
  Kobe             Bryant
```

What you want to do is loop through the model and depending on which column you want to check against, that will be the `column` you pass to `getValueAt(row, column)`. So you could do something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String name = jTextField1.getText();

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if (((String)model.getValueAt(i, 0)).equals(name)) {
            model.removeRow(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I use `0` for the `getValueAt()`, checking for the `First Name` column. If a name equals, the row is deleted.

If I type in `Lebron`, the row of `Lebron James` will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i < tableModel.getRowCount()) {
    //if the value at (i, 0) match the specified value the row will be removed

if the row removed all row will move up and their index will be changed
so you have to add a condition if the value from the table doesn't match 
the specified value the iterator i will iterate by one to jump to the next 
row


if (((String)tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0)).equals(value)) {
    tableModel.removeRow(i);
}else {
    ++i;
}

}
```